# Wicket FloatConverter setNumberFormat

Tags: wicket

In Wicket 6 the FloatConverter class had a setNumberFormat method.

In Wicket 7 it is no longer available.

I use it to modify the default limit of 3 decimals for a text field.
Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AbstractDecimalConverter#newNumberFormat(Locale)` for this. You can override it and configure the specifics.

```
public class MyFloatConverter extends FloatConverter {
  @Override protected NumberFormat newNumberFormat(final Locale locale)
    {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
        nf.setXyz(); // <<- customize the NumberFormat here 
        return nf;
    }
}
```

The you can setup this converter to be the default one in YourApplication.java:

```
  @Override protected ConverterLocator newConverterLocator()
  {
        ConverterLocator cl = super.newConverterLocator();
        cl.set(Float.class, new MyFloatConverter());
        return cl;
    }
}
```

or in a specific Component by overriding its `#getConverter(Class)` method;

Comment: Can you please give a short example.

Answer (score 0):

I used your MyFloatConverter like this for my TextField:

```
@Override
public final IConverter getConverter(Class type) {
    FloatConverter fc = new MyFloatConverter();
    return fc;
}
```